# MySQL Query grouping and counting results

Tags: mysql

here's my current query - it shows cities and a distance value:

```
SELECT city, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.228482) ) * cos( radians( geo_breit
 ) ) * cos( radians( geo_lang ) - radians(6.772457) ) + sin( radians(51.228482) ) * sin( radians( geo_breit
 ) ) ) )
   AS distance
   FROM partner HAVING distance < 50 
   ORDER BY city
```

which outputs:

[image]

i'm totally lost in grouping the data so it would return the following

```
city                    total         max_distance
-------------------------------------------------------------
Bedburg                 2             29.445788818447983
Bergheim                2             32.83341311371813
Bergisch Gladbach       4             39.62206615477636
Bochum                  1             43.15766028349356
...
```

**EDIT:** i added the actual query, the problem is that grouping/max doesn't work when using the `HAVING` keyword .. any ideas?

Comment: what do you try so far?

Comment: Simply `SELECT city, count(*), max(distance) FROM table Group by city` should work

Comment: _`here's my current query`_  Where???

Answer (score 1):

Either you use a nested query like this:

```
SELECT cities.city,
       count(*) as total,
       max(cities.distance) as max_distance
FROM (SELECT city,
            ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.228482) ) * cos( radians( geo_breit ) ) * cos( radians( geo_lang ) - radians(6.772457) ) + sin( radians(51.228482) ) * sin( radians( geo_breit) ) ) ) AS distance
       FROM partner HAVING distance < 50 
       ORDER BY city) as cities
  GROUP BY cities.city
```

**Or** you could try it with a where clause instead of a having

```
    SELECT city, count(*),
            max( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.228482) ) * cos( radians( geo_breit ) ) * cos( radians( geo_lang ) - radians(6.772457) ) + sin( radians(51.228482) ) * sin( radians( geo_breit) ) ) ) AS max_distance
       FROM partner 
       WHERE (6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.228482) ) * cos( radians( geo_breit ) ) * cos( radians( geo_lang ) - radians(6.772457) ) + sin( radians(51.228482) ) * sin( radians( geo_breit) ) ) < 50 
       ORDER BY city
       GROUP BY city
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT city, COUNT(city) as total, MAX(distance) AS max_distance
FROM table
GROUP BY city
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT` function count the number of occurrences and `MAX` function to find the maximum distance value with <kbd>[GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)</kbd>

**Query**

```
select city, count(city) as total, max(distance) as max_distance
from your_table_name
group by city;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT city, COUNT(city) total, MAX(distance) max_distance
FROM table
GROUP BY city
```

The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.